# Saving an array for data persistence gets a null pointer exception with gson

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, output

I am not going to post ALL the code, because there is hundreds of lines, but I will post the lines that are returned with my null pointer exception in LOGCAT, as well as the LOADFROMFILE And SAVETOFILE methods I use for the Gson serialization and data storage.

First error points here:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(SAVEFILE,0); // This line is the error
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
```

Second point:

```
AddClaim cla = new AddClaim();
cla.saveInFile(claim); // This line is the error
```

Third point:

```
public void addClaim(Claim claim){
    getClaimList().addClaim(claim);
```

Fourth point:

```
this.edate = getDateFromDatePicket(edatePicker);
addClaims(v);
```

Fifth/final point:

```
public void addClaims(View v){
    ClaimListController ct = new ClaimListController();
    Claim addClaim = new Claim(name, sdate, edate);
    ct.addClaim(addClaim);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Added "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now it seems to me these errors all have in common that I am trying to add a new claim. HOWEVER, when I remove the file persistence code and just run it with no storage, the code works and the claims show on my app. This must mean that it is not the claims that are coming through as null but something else? What is that something else?

Oh, and here are the two methods in Add Claim I use to Save and Load the data from file:

As an attribute of the class I have:

```
String SAVEFILE = "file.sav";
```

Then the rest of the code and then the two methods for loading and saving:

```
public void saveInFile(Claim claim) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(SAVEFILE,0);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        gson.toJson(claim, osw);
        osw.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Recover those persistent data created in the save function
private ArrayList<Claim> loadFromFile() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Claim> claim = new ArrayList<Claim>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(SAVEFILE);
        //Based on http://google.gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/dos/javadoc/com/google/gson/Gson.html
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Claim>>(){}.getType();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        claim = gson.fromJson(isr, listType);
        fis.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (claim == null){
        claim = new ArrayList<Claim>();
    }
    return claim;
}
```

Please let me know what else I need.

```
Here is the LOGCAT

02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093): Process: app.zioueche_travelexpense, PID: 23093
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     ... 11 more
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:197)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at app.zioueche_travelexpense.AddClaim.saveInFile(AddClaim.java:244)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at app.zioueche_travelexpense.ClaimsList.addClaim(ClaimsList.java:37)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at app.zioueche_travelexpense.ClaimListController.addClaim(ClaimListController.java:19)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at app.zioueche_travelexpense.NewClaim.addClaims(NewClaim.java:34)
02-01 01:05:37.105: E/AndroidRuntime(23093):     at app.zioueche_travelexpense.NewClaim.getEDate(NewClaim.java:68)
```

Line 244 starts with:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(SAVEFILE,0);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    gson.toJson(claim, osw);
    osw.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Looks like a `Context` issue. How/where is `ct` initialized (assuming that is a `Context`)? Also, "I am not going to post ALL the code," thank you for that

Comment: for CT, it is just a controller i made to add the claims.  Uhm. I initialize it right above the line where i use it
This is what it looks like:
look at comments error 5

Comment: What is at line 244 of `AddClaim`?

Comment: last block of code in comments. just added it

Answer (score 0):

In your loadFromFile() method add these four lines at the very top:

```
File myFile = new File(SAVEFILE);
System.out.println("Method 1, file exists?: " + myFile.exists());
File myFile2 = new File(getFilesDir(), "/" + SAVEFILE);
System.out.println("Method 2, file exists?: " + myFile2.exists());
```

If in both you get false then I don't know the answer.
If you get true at the second then you probably need to provide the absolute path when you look for your file.

Comment: They both print false